# How to use SHA-1 as a PRNG?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, sha-1

Is there any special parameters for using SHA-1 for generating pseudo-random numbers? What are the differences between SHA-1 as a PRNG and original SHA-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible constructions but the simplest is probably to initalize a counter with a random seed and hash the counter to produce more random bits and then increment the counter.

Comment: And what about having a sequence made by using SHA-1 on the previous hash and having some big number as a starting value? (it will be a seed). 

`counter=10`
`seed=12345 `
`r=sha1(seed)` 
`for i in range(counter):`
`    print(r)`
`#making new random number`
`    r=sha1(r)`

Will it be ok?

Comment: Yes, that is also ok, you are expected to repeat after aproximately 2^80 steps which is less than what I proposed but should still be sufficient for most purposes. SHA-1 is not considered secure but due to no viable pre-image attack I do not know of a viable attack on either construction. Regardless of PRNG you need a high entropy seed for security.

Comment: What?  No!  That is not OK!  The function $k \mapsto H(k) \mathbin\| H(H(k)) \mathbin\| H(H(H(k))) \mathbin\| \dotsb$ is absolutely not a secure pseudorandom generator.  Anyone who sees one block of output can trivially predict all subsequent blocks of output.

Comment: Yes of course, it only works if you output a small part of your state.